# обернуть все элементы определенного div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть div. при помощи jquery или javascript обернуть все элементы внутри.

Comment: на примере wrapinner приведу

Comment: @eenigmage что значит `обернуть`?

Answer (score 2):

`.wrapInner`:

```js
$('.block').wrapInner('<div class="new" />');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

`.wrapAll`:

```js
$('.block > div').wrapAll('<div class="new" />');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуемся `wrapInner`

```js
$('.button').wrapInner('<div class="button-bg"></div>');
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.button .button-bg {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  text
</div>
```

Comment: А как теперь наоборот удалить этот обертывающий div?

Comment: Функциями jQuery

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```js
var item = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  item[i].outerHTML = '<div class="wrap">' + item[i].outerHTML + '</div>';
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.wrap {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```